# Run a javascript snippet before loading a website on chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

On the website I do have "enableTab = false". For the testing purpose, i'm using Chrome with Console developer tool. What I need to do is to set enableTab = false, then refresh the browser and see the result. I try to set directly in console "enableTab = true" then refresh the page, but the variable automatically changes back to false.

I can test it manually by setting the enableTab in the code, but it becomes more time-consuming when I have to redo the task with many other flags.

Is it anyway that I can set the "enableTab = true" in the console, then make sure it's always set to true when I browse around the website (after refresh).

Thank you

Comment: Set a breakpoint in top of a file.

Comment: Exactly what I need, thank you

Answer (score 1):

try initilizing and setting your variables from localStorage.

in your initializing code try something like:

```
enableTab = localStorage[0] || false;
```

then when you want to test what it will look like, in the console you would type:

```
localStorage[0] = true;
```

and refresh the page.

Comment: thanks, it would be a nice approach but I try not to touch the code as much as possible because I will need to clean up later. So the above answer which asks to set breakpoint is really what  i need.

Answer (score 0):

You can add parameters to the URL. For example, if your URL is `http://hostname/path`, replace it by `http://hostname/path?enabledTab=true`, and then inside your web page include this:

```
enableTab = location.search.includes('enabledTab=true')
```

The nice thing about the URL approach is that it is easy to use in manual testing scenarios like you described, and also in automatic testing scenarios where you want a test script to control the behavior of the application.

Comment: The url itself has already had a query so I guess it will make it more complicated. thanks!

Comment: It's o.k. to add more parameters to an existing query

Comment: new thing to try and i will do that, thank for the knowledge!